# The SetTimeout not working on the code array propotype?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
function vFunction() {
    var sSplit = tText[counter].split("");
    sSplit.forEach((element) => { 
        myElement.innerHTML = sSplit.slice(0, pos).join("");
        pos += increment;   
    }); 
    timeLoop = setTimeout(vFunction, 100);
}

vFunction();
```

Currently set timeout is set on the function so when the function is done finishing that time animation is visible only on the last character, but I intend to see the animation on every character.
I tried this one: based on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

```
setTimeout(
    sSplit.forEach((element) => { 
    myElement.innerHTML = sSplit.slice(0, pos).join("");, 
    1.0*1000);

    pos += increment;   
});
```

But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the documentation, setTimeout requires a second argument, rather than the function to run it self, if needs the delay to know when to run it, either in seconds, or millieseconds.

so, try this:

```
setTimeout(
    sSplit.forEach((element) => { 
    element.innerHTML = sSplit.slice(0, pos).join("");, 
    1.0*1000);

    pos += increment;   
},1000);
```

1000 is 1000 miliseconds, or equal to 1 second

Comment: btw, you also used myElement instead of element, i fixed in the answer, but I couldnt help but dont get what you code seems to be doing, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Thanks, Should I give an additional code? Let me try if it works, I will update you.

Comment: I don't get what ", 1.0*1000);" is doing in lines 3-4.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error, check the closing of brackets. same here could not understand what is it doing here → 'I don't get what ", 1.0*1000);'